# RegEx search returns -1 even though phrase is definitely present in the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, angular, typescript

I am importing an excel file using `xlsx` in angular, where the excel file is imported as an object of arrays, with each array being a row of the excel file and each item in each array is a cell within it's respective row. See below for how this is done

```js
onFileChange(event: any) 
  {
    const inputFile: DataTransfer = <DataTransfer>(event.target); 
    const fileReader: FileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.onload = (event: any) => 
    {
      const binaryString: string = event.target.result;
      const workBook: XLSX.WorkBook = XLSX.read(binaryString, { type: 'binary', sheetStubs: true}); 
      /* sheetstubs true supposedly shows empty cells but isn't */

      const workSheetName: string = workBook.SheetNames[0];
      const workSheet: XLSX.WorkSheet = workBook.Sheets[workSheetName];

      this.data = <Array>(XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workSheet, 
      {header: 1, blankrows: true }));


    };
```

I am now trying to find the column which contains a manufacturer description by using a Regex search by looping through each of the arrays and searching for the term `cap` like so:

```js
getManufacturerDescriptionColumn()
  {
    console.log(this.data)
    for (const row in this.data)
    {

      var manDescriptIndex = row.search(/cap/i)
      console.log(manDescriptIndex)
      if (manDescriptIndex > -1) 
      {
       return manDescriptIndex
      }
    }
  }
```

however when ever I try this, even though the phrase cap is clearly present in some of the arrays when I run this, I am presented with all `-1` values indicating that the phrase is not found in any of the arrays. Below is an attached example where CAP is clearly present in a couple of the 15 rows of the excel file but I am still met with 15 -1 values.

[image: Example Manufacturer Description Column]

For example the array indexed at 
Any ideas why a regex search isn't identifying the phrase in this scenario when I do `console.log(this.data)` I can see the phrase cap like so,

[image: Array #13 in object of arrays]

I have also tried adding another layer of iteration to isolate the strings of the individual cells in the row also to no avail.

Comment: What does `row.search` exactly do?

Comment: @VLAZ as you can see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/search)

Comment: I may be incorrect but my understanding is that it is a method to search a string to see if it contains a regex expression?

Comment: Also, for the record if `getManufacturerDescriptionColumn` returns `-1` that is exceptionally odd - it *only* returns a value if said value is more than `-1`, otherwise it will implicitly return `undefined`. It should be impossible for it to return any negative number.

Comment: sorry bad syntax doesn't return but the console.log(manDescripIndex) that I called to see what values rows.search was giving were all giving -1

Comment: Try to write a test for that and make it a pure function that takes in some `data` and return some `otherData` this way you can create a funcion that works passed the data you think are passing and then just fix this...
TDD is a great approach for this

Comment: Are you sure you don't have any errors in the console? Some of the array members seem to be numbers, so if you call `(1).search(/cap/i)` that should throw an error.

Comment: Wait, I'm getting even more confused - if `this.data` contains *arrays* of data, then `row` be an array. So, calling `row.search()` would be invoking the non-existent method `search` from said array. Which should still throw an error.

Comment: @VLAZ I did try to iterate one step further to iterate over each individual cell and search for the phrase prior to asking the question (I think I edited my question properly) and received a -1 value for each cell as well

Comment: @AlejandroVales I'm not super familiar with TDD do you mean maybe creating a simpler spreadsheet and then testing that against expected values from that test sheet?

Comment: Could be a scoping issue but not this case, as printing `this.data` was giving him what he thinks

Comment: I considered the scoping issue already but as @AlejandroVales points out this.data is printing precisely what it should be

Comment: @Banani720 TDD is good for making things more testable, and in this case creating a more simple scenario (without the excelsheet) to discard other issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can clearly read here [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) you are using the loop `for..in` which is a mistake, and you should be using `for..of` instead. Explanation below

`for..in` is made to iterate around objects, which actually works for arrays, but is just giving you the indexes, which in this case will be 0,1,2 and so on...

If you want to get the values you will have to use the `for..of` loop [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)

You will see this more clearly if you print `console.log(row)` before the check

Comment: I completely missed it was `for..in`. For some reason I kept reading it as `for..of` since I specifically looked at just that line. The results made no sense given the code....unless `row` was a string which it would be the case if it was just the keys.

Comment: ahhhhh very silly oversight on my part didn't even occur for me to look there thank you very much and sorry to trouble you with a simple mistake like this

Answer (score 0):

Ok so @AlejandroVales was definitely right in his answer so I'm not gonna take away that well earned check mark but... I have an update to fully get the solution because while changing `in` to `of` was instrumental to me getting to the point I needed to get, there was more to be done and in the spirit of sharing information and frankly good karma, I have for others who run into a similar issue... a solution. Rather than trying to use array methods in order to see if I could find what I am looking for I tested each element in each array AGAINST a regular expression, AKA I flipped the problem on it's head a little bit. So to clarify take a look at the code block below

```js
var cap = new RegExp(/cap/i)
    for (const row of this.data)
    {
      for (let cell = 0; cell<row.length; cell++)
      {
        if (cap.test(row[cell]))
        {
          return cell
        }
      }
    }
```

First set a variable equal to a regex, then iterate to a level where I am iterating over each cell in each array (each array is a row of the excel document in this case), then find the cell that returns a TRUE value and poof problem solved. If I didn't do a good job explaining this solution feel free to leave a comment below I am no expert but figured it's only right try my best to give value to a community that has given me so much value previously.